# How to use regular expression in a JenkinsFile multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've a multibranch pipeline jenkins file. I would like to be able to use a custom workspace, which includes this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node{
            label 'windows-node'            
            customWorkspace "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"    
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

I would like to be able to extract one part of my branch name to do the regular expression.

my branches have the following structures:

- master
- develop
- feature/BR-1-some-text
- bugs/BR-5-some-text

And I would like my workspace to be only BR-X if present, so in my case:

- master
- develop
- BR-1
- BR-5

I'm totally capable to do one regular expression to extract this from this text, but I don't see how to extract this regex and use it as customWorkspace.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If understand correctly, I use the condition checks in pipeline like this, I abort my pipeline if branch is not of this pattern.

```
when {
                not {
                    anyOf {
                        branch 'feat/*';
                        branch 'feature/*'
                        branch 'bug/*'
                        branch 'bugfix/*'
                        branch 'release/*'
                        branch 'hotfix/*'
                        branch 'PR-*'
            branch 'e2e/*'
            branch 'develop'
            branch 'fix/*'
                        }
                    }
                }
```

or you can also use

```
when { branch pattern: "release-\\d+", comparator: "REGEXP"}
```